# Angular2 md-autocomplete persisting previously selected value

Tags: angular, angular-material2, md-autocomplete

I am using Angular2 and have an   within an  which is populated with values from

The scenario:-

1. User selects a value from the autocomplete, it is displayed in the input box correctly.
2. User then clears the selection by pressing backspace leaving the input box empty/with no text BUT the previously selected value is still in the autocomplete..(persisting)

Same problem occurs in Chrome and Edge...

HTML

```
<md-input-container>
   <input mdInput placeholder="Enter Code" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" 
   [formControl]="stateCtrl">
</md-input-container>

<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete" md-no-cache="true">
     <md-option *ngFor="let c of codeNumbers " [value]="c">{{c}}</md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

TYPESCRIPT

```
export class VehicleComponent implements OnInit
{

    public codeNumbers: any[];
    stateCtrl: FormControl;
    public myForm: FormGroup;

    constructor()
    {
        this.stateCtrl = new FormControl();

        this.stateCtrl.valueChanges.subscribe(name =>
        {
            if (name.toString().length >= 5) 
            {
                this.GetCode((name) as string);
            } 
            else
            {
                this.codeNumbers = null;
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Getcode() method as requested

```
    public GetCode(code:string)
    {
            "use strict";

            this.CodeService.GetCODEData(code).subscribe(result => {
                this.codeNumbers = ((result) as any);
         });

    }
```

Attachments show the problem - any help highly appreciated...

[image: Valid Selection]

[image: Persisted value in Autocomplete]

Comment: can you add `GetCode()` function in your question too?

Comment: I have added the GetCode() method

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it, it's working properly in this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rernZocxgiZY4Z8vxtf0?p=preview). See if you can recreate the issue in a plunker, and share the link in your question.

Comment: can't see where you have declared "codeNumbers "

Comment: I updated the plunker

Comment: working on Plunker but still not working in my .NET project

Comment: @MaiurLaximidas add a console.log in the subscribe block to see what `name.toString()` is as your deleting. This should have nothing to do with your surrounding setup.

Comment: @WillHowell console.log output...                                                                                           greater than 5 char VWSR9EFRC412358
greater than 5 char VWSR9EFRC41235
greater than 5 char VWSR9EFRC4123
greater than 5 char VWSR9EFRC412
greater than 5 char VWSR9EFRC41
greater than 5 char VWSR9EFRC4
greater than 5 char VWSR9EFRC
greater than 5 char VWSR9EFR
greater than 5 char VWSR9EF
greater than 5 char VWSR9E
greater than 5 char VWSR9
less than 5 char VWSR
less than 5 char VWS
less than 5 char VW
less than 5 char V
less than 5 char

Comment: @WillHowell - the problem occurs when I clear all characters using backspace in one go - if I clear one character at a time there is no problem...results below from console.log